# Spring Tool Suite (Eclipse): Update to 4.7 causes multiple SLF4J bindings

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, maven, eclipse-plugin, osgi-bundle

After I updated my STS based on Eclipse to 4.7, the build starts with a warning:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/A329865/OneDrive/Apps/sts-4.6.0.RELEASE/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.16.0.20200610-1735/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/C:/Users/A329865/OneDrive/Apps/sts-4.6.0.RELEASE/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/5/0/.cp/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/A329865/OneDrive/Apps/sts-4.6.0.RELEASE/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.16.0.20200610-1735/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/C:/Users/A329865/OneDrive/Apps/sts-4.6.0.RELEASE/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/5/0/.cp/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
```

Even when I use a new STS 4.7 the same warning occurs.

I think the problem can be found in this line:

```
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/C:/Users/A329865/OneDrive/Apps/sts-4.6.0.RELEASE/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/5/0/.cp/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
```

But I don't know how to deactivate it. It's not a plugin or jar-file. It seems to be a part of the osgi bundle.

Maybe my assumption is wrong, but can anybody help me?

Comment: This is probably a bug in Eclipse 2020-06 which STS 4.7 is now based on. See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=506676

Comment: Thanks for that info. It seems to be the same problem. Maybe I should use an external Maven installation. I will try it.

Comment: I tried out to build with an external Maven installation (V3.6.1, V3.6.3). This didn't solve the problem for me. The warning still occurs.